# Como criar Parâmetros para o IReport

Tags: java, imagem, ireport, parâmetros, impressão

Eu estou desenvolvendo um Software em Java onde o usuário realiza cadastros. Cada produto cadastrado poderá ser impresso. Cada produto poderá ter várias imagens e essas imagens deverão ser impressas junto com os dados dos outros produtos. Pode acontecer de não haver nenhuma imagem. Eu gostaria de em tempo real criar parâmetros no formulários para passar cada imagem para ser exibida no iReport e poder ser impressa. Os dados já estão sendo exibidos. Falta só as imagens. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A imagem precisa ser passada como um BufferedReader pelo parametro do Map, ler a imagem a partir de um ImageIO pode facilitar.

Não deve ser preciso uma verificação para deixar como opcional, mas verifique.

Dentro do .jrxml terá que setar um parametro passando o nome cuja representação é a chave do Map, e a classe na qual vai representar a Image, segue um exemplo

```
<parameter name="CLIENT_IMAGE" class="java.awt.Image" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Como já passou outros dados em texto, a image não foge muito de como é feito.